# Find nearest point given coordinates from another table

Tags: postgis, spatial-join, spatial-query

So I have two tables, one table is called `stores` which has the name of the store as well as the `geom` column that contains the coordinates for the stores. The other table is `customers` which has the coordinates of the customer's address.

I'm trying to create a new column in the `customer` table with the nearest store given the customer's coordinates. I've tried something like this but it doesn't work:

`UPDATE customers SET storename = 
    SELECT storename 
    FROM stores 
    ORDER BY geom <-> ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(customers.geom)',4326) LIMIT 1
);`

Comment: Can you elaborate on *what* doesn't work? Is there any error message?

Comment: @underdark I'm not sure the duplicate flag on this question is correct.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues with your statement:

1. There is a missing parenthesis before your SELECT (it matches the one just before the semi-colon).
2. It appears you are unnecessarily converting the customers.geom to a point set as 4326 SRID.
3. Are you wanting to transform or set the SRID for customers.geom?  I have two solutions below to cover either answer.

This statement assumes that the customers' geom is in a different SRID than the stores' geom:

```
UPDATE customers SET storename = (
    SELECT storename 
    FROM stores 
    ORDER BY geom <-> ST_Transform(customers.geom,4326) LIMIT 1
    );
```

And this statement assumes that the customers' geom is the same as the stores' geom:

```
UPDATE customers SET storename = (
    SELECT storename 
    FROM stores 
    ORDER BY geom <-> customers.geom LIMIT 1
    );
```

You also mentioned that you are trying to create a new column... that column must exist before you run an UPDATE statement.  Here is an example of how to add a column to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE customers ADD COLUMN storename CHARACTER VARYING(50);
```